# Rotatable 3D model in web page

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, vector, svg

I have quite a bit of a quandary:

I want to create a 3D model of the human body, embed it in a web page and give the user the ability to rotate it.

I have considered a few modelling libraries, CSS, SVG etc (I've never used HTML5 Canvas) but to be honest I am not sure if this is even possible.

Also - IF the above is possible then would it then be possible to manipulate the joints eg bring the knee up or the elbow in?

My main thought is building the models in SVG and having the model rotate in steps of say 36 degrees via Javascript and then it may be possible to manipulate the joints from there.

I am willing to learn new languages to do this if need be.

Thanks in advance and hope that someone can help me. Even if to tell me that it's not possible.

John

Comment: Is there any code to work with?

Comment: None I'm afraid as I don't know where to start. I don't want to be entering data only to find the technology I've used will not work therefore I've tried to establish the technology I need to use early on.

Comment: I have had [threejs.org](http://threejs.org) suggested on Twitter. If nothing better comes from this thread I shall add this as an answer as it looks like an ideal starting point :-)

Comment: View my answer given below if it is usefull, mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks Guys for your help. However, I honestly can't see why I've been marked down for the question. I have spent that past day researching this (on and off so for about 7 hours) and I have come up with all sorts of libraries etc as well as differing technologies but none of them fitted the bill. The answer (threejs) is the closest to what I'm looking for but I had honestly not seen that one. After researching it all I still wasn't sure whether it was possible and provided all the information I thought was necessary. I  wasn't willing to start coding in 1 language only to have to start again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard and beautiful way: THREEJS. http://threejs.org/
easy way: create an image with each frame set it as background in a container and then change the background-position accordingly (this will allow to rotate on one axis only, and no joints manipulation).

I suggest you learn threejs (if you have enough time) their examples are great and it's not that hard.

Browser support also plays a big role in your choice, threejs uses canvas, so it's a pretty new feature. You could use both solutions, threejs on newer browsers and a sprite for crappy old ies

Comment: Thanks Jonas, this is my personal project and I am more than willing to learn new skills etc so learning threejs will not be a problem. I had honestly not seen threejs - The nearest I had gotten was sprite.js. I will accept your answer as the correct one as you were the one to reply with the best answer and an alternative as well. Thanks again, John

Answer (score 1):

This code is from three.js this can be usefull for this question.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>three.js webgl - cloth simulation</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: Monospace;
                background-color: #000;
                color: #000;
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            #info {
                text-align: center;
                padding: 10px;
                z-index: 10;
                width: 100%;
                position: absolute;
            }

            a {
                text-decoration: underline;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            #stats { position: absolute; top:0; left: 0 }
            #stats #fps { background: transparent !important }
            #stats #fps #fpsText { color: #aaa !important }
            #stats #fps #fpsGraph { display: none }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="info">Simple Cloth Simulation<br/>
            Verlet integration with Constrains relaxation<br/>
            Toggle: <a onclick="rotate = !rotate;">Camera</a> |
            <a onclick="wind = !wind;">Wind</a> |
            <a onclick="sphere.visible = !sphere.visible;">Ball</a> |
            <a onclick="togglePins();">Pins</a>
        </div>

        <script src="../build/three.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/Detector.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/Cloth.js"></script>

        <script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fragmentShaderDepth">

            uniform sampler2D texture;
            varying vec2 vUV;

            vec4 pack_depth( const in float depth ) {

                const vec4 bit_shift = vec4( 256.0 * 256.0 * 256.0, 256.0 * 256.0, 256.0, 1.0 );
                const vec4 bit_mask  = vec4( 0.0, 1.0 / 256.0, 1.0 / 256.0, 1.0 / 256.0 );
                vec4 res = fract( depth * bit_shift );
                res -= res.xxyz * bit_mask;
                return res;

            }

            void main() {

                vec4 pixel = texture2D( texture, vUV );

                if ( pixel.a < 0.5 ) discard;

                gl_FragData[ 0 ] = pack_depth( gl_FragCoord.z );

            }
        </script>

        <script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexShaderDepth">

            varying vec2 vUV;

            void main() {

                vUV = 0.75 * uv;

                vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );

                gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;

            }

        </script>

        <script>

            /* testing cloth simulation */

            var pinsFormation = [];
            var pins = [6];

            pinsFormation.push( pins );

            pins = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ];
            pinsFormation.push( pins );

            pins = [ 0 ];
            pinsFormation.push( pins );

            pins = []; // cut the rope ;)
            pinsFormation.push( pins );

            pins = [ 0, cloth.w ]; // classic 2 pins
            pinsFormation.push( pins );

            pins = pinsFormation[ 1 ];


            function togglePins() {

                pins = pinsFormation[ ~~( Math.random() * pinsFormation.length ) ];

            }

            if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

            var container, stats;
            var camera, scene, renderer;

            var clothGeometry;
            var sphere;
            var object, arrow;

            var rotate = true;

            init();
            animate();

            function init() {

                container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                document.body.appendChild( container );

                // scene

                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0xcce0ff, 500, 10000 );

                // camera

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 30, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
                camera.position.y = 50;
                camera.position.z = 1500;
                scene.add( camera );

                // lights

                var light, materials;

                scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x666666 ) );

                light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xdfebff, 1.75 );
                light.position.set( 50, 200, 100 );
                light.position.multiplyScalar( 1.3 );

                light.castShadow = true;
                //light.shadowCameraVisible = true;

                light.shadowMapWidth = 2048;
                light.shadowMapHeight = 2048;

                var d = 300;

                light.shadowCameraLeft = -d;
                light.shadowCameraRight = d;
                light.shadowCameraTop = d;
                light.shadowCameraBottom = -d;

                light.shadowCameraFar = 1000;
                light.shadowDarkness = 0.5;

                scene.add( light );

                light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0x3dff0c, 0.35 );
                light.position.set( 0, -1, 0 );

                scene.add( light );

                // cloth material

                var clothTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'textures/patterns/circuit_pattern.png' );
                clothTexture.wrapS = clothTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
                clothTexture.anisotropy = 16;

                var clothMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { alphaTest: 0.5, ambient: 0xffffff, color: 0xffffff, specular: 0x030303, emissive: 0x111111, shiness: 10, map: clothTexture, side: THREE.DoubleSide } );

                // cloth geometry
                clothGeometry = new THREE.ParametricGeometry( clothFunction, cloth.w, cloth.h );
                clothGeometry.dynamic = true;
                clothGeometry.computeFaceNormals();

                var uniforms = { texture:  { type: "t", value: clothTexture } };
                var vertexShader = document.getElementById( 'vertexShaderDepth' ).textContent;
                var fragmentShader = document.getElementById( 'fragmentShaderDepth' ).textContent;

                // cloth mesh

                object = new THREE.Mesh( clothGeometry, clothMaterial );
                object.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );
                object.castShadow = true;
                object.receiveShadow = true;
                scene.add( object );

                object.customDepthMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( { uniforms: uniforms, vertexShader: vertexShader, fragmentShader: fragmentShader } );

                // sphere

                var ballGeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry( ballSize, 20, 20 );
                var ballMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffffff } );

                sphere = new THREE.Mesh( ballGeo, ballMaterial );
                sphere.castShadow = true;
                sphere.receiveShadow = true;
                scene.add( sphere );

                // arrow

                arrow = new THREE.ArrowHelper( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0 ), new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ), 50, 0xff0000 );
                arrow.position.set( -200, 0, -200 );
                // scene.add( arrow );

                // ground

                var initColor = new THREE.Color( 0x497f13 );
                var initTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.generateDataTexture( 1, 1, initColor );

                var groundMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, specular: 0x111111, map: initTexture } );

                var groundTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "textures/terrain/grasslight-big.jpg", undefined, function() { groundMaterial.map = groundTexture } );
                groundTexture.wrapS = groundTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
                groundTexture.repeat.set( 25, 25 );
                groundTexture.anisotropy = 16;

                var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 20000, 20000 ), groundMaterial );
                mesh.position.y = -250;
                mesh.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;
                mesh.receiveShadow = true;
                scene.add( mesh );

                // poles

                var poleGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 5, 375, 5 );
                var poleMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, specular: 0x111111, shiness: 100 } );

                var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( poleGeo, poleMat );
                mesh.position.x = -125;
                mesh.position.y = -62;
                mesh.receiveShadow = true;
                mesh.castShadow = true;
                scene.add( mesh );

                var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( poleGeo, poleMat );
                mesh.position.x = 125;
                mesh.position.y = -62;
                mesh.receiveShadow = true;
                mesh.castShadow = true;
                scene.add( mesh );

                var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.BoxGeometry( 255, 5, 5 ), poleMat );
                mesh.position.y = -250 + 750/2;
                mesh.position.x = 0;
                mesh.receiveShadow = true;
                mesh.castShadow = true;
                scene.add( mesh );

                var gg = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 10, 10, 10 );
                var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( gg, poleMat );
                mesh.position.y = -250;
                mesh.position.x = 125;
                mesh.receiveShadow = true;
                mesh.castShadow = true;
                scene.add( mesh );

                var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( gg, poleMat );
                mesh.position.y = -250;
                mesh.position.x = -125;
                mesh.receiveShadow = true;
                mesh.castShadow = true;
                scene.add( mesh );

                //

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                renderer.setClearColor( scene.fog.color );

                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                renderer.gammaInput = true;
                renderer.gammaOutput = true;

                renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;

                //

                stats = new Stats();
                container.appendChild( stats.domElement );

                //

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

                sphere.visible = !true

            }

            //

            function onWindowResize() {

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            }

            //

            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                var time = Date.now();

                windStrength = Math.cos( time / 7000 ) * 20 + 40;
                windForce.set( Math.sin( time / 2000 ), Math.cos( time / 3000 ), Math.sin( time / 1000 ) ).normalize().multiplyScalar( windStrength );
                arrow.setLength( windStrength );
                arrow.setDirection( windForce );

                simulate(time);
                render();
                stats.update();

            }

            function render() {

                var timer = Date.now() * 0.0002;

                var p = cloth.particles;

                for ( var i = 0, il = p.length; i < il; i ++ ) {

                    clothGeometry.vertices[ i ].copy( p[ i ].position );

                }

                clothGeometry.computeFaceNormals();
                clothGeometry.computeVertexNormals();

                clothGeometry.normalsNeedUpdate = true;
                clothGeometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

                sphere.position.copy( ballPosition );

                if ( rotate ) {

                    camera.position.x = Math.cos( timer ) * 1500;
                    camera.position.z = Math.sin( timer ) * 1500;

                }

                camera.lookAt( scene.position );

                renderer.render( scene, camera );

            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Karthik, Thanks for providing the code. I will go and learn threejs tonight and will dissect the examples they have and slowly build up the model that I need. Thanks agin